# MySQL, Order by column with strings in English and Other language (Hebrew)

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, hebrew

I have table with column `category_name` and data `1,9,A,B,C,א,ב,ג`

Data both in english (1,9,A,B,C) and hebrew (א,ב,ג).

How can I order this data Hebrew first and then English ?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY category_name ..... ??
```

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html) about charsets and collations supported by MySQL but I'm afraid you cannot do it without additional information (like a column that says if `category_name` is in English or Hebrew). Using the correct collation helps MySQL sort the strings using the natural characters order in the target language (for example, in Romanian, place "ă" and "â" near "a" and not at the end of the alphabet, where they are located if it checks their Unicode codes).

Comment: may be `select * from category order by case when category_name not regexp '[A-Za-z0-9]' then 0 else 1 end,category_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can try a workaround:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY IF(category_name <= '~', 2, 1) ASC, category_name
```

If you have categories whose names start with `'~'` then use another character that is located between ASCII and Hebrew characters in the Unicode list.